# Can neon tetras and African Dwarf Frogs live together?

Tags: aquarium, fish

I'm about to cycle a 10 gal fish tank with maybe 1-2 neon tetras, and I was just wondering if African Dwarf Frogs and neon tetras would be a good choice.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Do you plan to fill the tank completely with water, or will there be space for the frog to climb?

Answer (score 5):

They can be kept together, but unfortunately not in a tank that small. Tetras are a schooling fish, and should be kept in a group of at least 6 individuals (https://www.fishkeepingworld.com/faq/how-many-neon-tetras-should-be-kept-together/). You could potentially keep 6 tetras in the 10 gallon, but adding the frogs on top would likely overload your tank.